# jQuery Quicksand plugin doesn't get positions correct

Tags: jquery, html, css, quicksand

I'm working on sorting a single list of elements using the quicksand plugin for `jQuery`. Sorting is working fine, but when quicksand moves the sorted elements to their new positions it gets it completely wrong.

**[Site Link](http://www.meepmedia.com.au/GC2/Sorting/index2.html)**

If you click 'Fighting' for example, you'll see **3 images drop down** along the **left hand** side then suddenly appear in their correct places.

Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my CSS. I simply removed:

```
ul.portfolio {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    width:auto;
}
```

Now it works fine.